# Run process when django server shut down

Tags: python, django, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I run a Django Web Server by Python 3 with a Raspberry Pi. 
During the common business i use some `RPi.GPIO` commands (set Pin to `GPIO.HIGH` and `GPIO.LOW`).

When I restart the Django Server I receive a warning, that some Pins are used.
It is possible to ignor this warning, but I strongly believe, that ignoring the warning is not a good practice.

- Is it a good solution to ignor the warning?
- Is it possible to run a proces after the shut down process has been finished, to run `RPi.cleanup()`?
- Is it possible to run th `RPi.cleanup()`or an other process before the server runs, or in the `ready()` method at the `apps.py` file?

Answer (score 0):

You can launch the server using a custom script; and in this script - make sure that the system is in the ready state (ie, PINs are available) before you launch.

You can use the same trick when the system is shutdown.

How you will plug into these states depends on how you are running the server in the first place.

For example, if you are using uwsgi you can use the [`as-user-atexit` and `pre-app` hooks](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Hooks.html).